# How to seal an overridden property

Tags: .net, inheritance, f#, c#-to-f#

Suppose I have a pair of obviously contrived C# classes like this:

```
public abstract class Foo {
    public abstract int[] LegalValues { get; }
    public virtual bool IsValueLegal(int val) {
        return Array.IndexOf(LegalValues, val) >= 0;
    }
}
```

and this:

```
public class Bar : Foo {
    static int[] _legalValues = new int[] { 0, 1 }; // whatever
    public sealed override int[] LegalValues 
        { get { return _legalValues; } }
    public sealed override bool IsValueLegal(int val)
        { return base.IsValueLegal(val); }
}
```

How do I do this in F#?  The obvious code for the properties:

```
[<Sealed>]
override this.LegalValues with get() = // ...

[<Sealed>]
override this.IsValueLegal value = // ...
```

Triggers an error because the SealedAttribute apparently can't be applied to members.
I can, of course, seal the entire class and thereby seal all members, but (and this is a **really important** but) is that I have a goal of matching an existing class signature **exactly** and the base class has other virtual/abstract members that should, ideally, remain overridable.

Comment: Hm, I did not even know that sealing individual methods was possible in C#/CLR!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are currently several limitations to F#'s support for OO, so you should not generally expect to be able to produce an F# class hierarchy which is identical to an arbitrary C# class hierarchy.  As far as I know, there is no way to override and seal a virtual method.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like F# defines the [Sealed Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353500.aspx) is defined with its AttributeTargets property set to Class only, its probably not possible to seal members.

This is probably *ok*, since inheritance and overriding functions is generally less idiomatic in F# than C#. I don't think you can really get what you want without rewriting in more F# idioms. Start with this:

```
type foo =
    | Bar
    | Baz
    | Qux
        with
            member this.LegalValues =
                match this with
                | Bar -> [0; 1]
                | Qux -> [-1; 0; 1]
                | Baz -> [0 .. 10 ]
            member this.IsValueLegal value =
                match this with
                | Baz -> value >= 0 && value <= 10
                | _ -> List.exists (fun x -> x = value) (this.LegalValues)
```

You can say that `Baz` "overrides" the `foo.IsValueLegal` member, all other types use the "base" function.

Comment: Interesting approach, but I can't use it - the base class defines a particular inheritance so I cannot redefine Foo under any circumstances and I am required in Bar to prevent someone from overriding these methods.  If I have to seal the whole class, then so be it.  While this will cut off certain operations, they could be simulated in other ways (adapters, etc).